# CakePHP Association

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have 2 tables:

1) Categories: 
id,
name.

2) News: 
id,
category_id,
title,
body

After baking all these things, it prepares the interface by which I have to add a news by clicking Add News. After that I have to manually select the category.

I want to click on some category (view) and there's an option 'Add News to this Category', and from there it goes to an action with the category_id, so that user does not need to select the category because its coming from an URL which knows which category is being used.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

First grab the `category_id` from URL:

```
$categoryId= $this->params['named']['category_id'];
```

Then on the form use hidden field:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('category_id', array('default'=>$categoryId));
```